# security topics

Tags: security, encryption, mobile

i have a course project to do on network security,
the project theme is lightweight security on mobile devices,sensors,rfids...
i am really finding it hard to get papers about any of these topics.
so what are some nice project topics that i can do?
thanks

Comment: My guess question related to community wiki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Network Security ppt

---

I assume U are looking for Presentations on network-security.

> http://www.cisco.com/warp/public/cc/so/neso/sqso/beggu_pl.pdf
>
> http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/braman/cs425/slides/security-overview.pdf
>
> [crypto.stanford.edu/cs155old/cs155-spring04/cs155-pp3-section.ppt](http://crypto.stanford.edu/cs155old/cs155-spring04/cs155-pp3-section.ppt)
>
> [www.cert.org/archive/ppt/info-security.ppt](http://www.cert.org/archive/ppt/info-security.ppt)
>
> [www.cs.cmu.edu/~srini/15-441/F02/lectures/lec21-security.ppt](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~srini/15-441/F02/lectures/lec21-security.ppt)

GoodLUCK!!

CVS @ 2600Hertz